# Cachekey generation from object state

Tags: caching, hash

**Background**

I am looking to purely store whether or not a query has already been performed.  If it has, the query should be run against a cache of data (internal db, out of process) and if not it should run against the original datasource (3rd party external webservice).  The motivation for this caching is that the number of calls we are allowed to make to this API is limited and we are likely to perform the same query multiple times.

After the query has been run once against the original datasource, it will only ever be run against the cached datasource in subsequent calls.  Note: I'm deliberately ignoring the question of cache expiration for the sake of simplicity in this question.

Given that each query may contain many parameters (currently only 5), and the number of parameters may increase over time I don't want to be querying the cached datasource with something like *"WHERE x AND y AND z AND a AND b AND c AND d AND..."*.

To that end, all I want is to know whether this exact query has been run before and if it has I'll assume the data for it is already available in the cached datastore (albeit in a different format).  I think some form of "cachekey" that identifies any query with the same parameters and associated values would work for me.  Every time I attempt a query I would just generate the cache key based on the state of the query object and check the cachekey store to establish if the query has ever been run before.  The cachekey store needs to faciliate fast lookups.

**Question**

What I'm finding tricky to work out is what this cachekey should look like and how to generate it.  So far I'm leaning towards

1. concatenate *interesting* query parameters and their values into a byte array
2. create an MD5 from the byte array
3. store this cachekey in a binary(16) indexed column

For the sake of argument I'm willing to accept that there will be some collisions that might result in the cache reporting that cached data is available for the query when it isn't given that the likelyhood is pretty small (although how small I'm not 100% sure).

Does the above solution for creating the cachekey seem reasonable or are there any other approaches that I should consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your potential solution is exactly what I've done in the past and it has worked well. I actually concatenated the method/call name, then all the parameter values together into a string, then ran MD5 on it and got my cache key.

I don't see how there could be collisions. If you change a parameter value, the cache key would be different, which would potentially bring back different data.

(All that to say I'm not sure what you mean by "interesting" parameters.)

Comment: MD5 has collision issues but they are (depending on the input) rare.  From what I've read, if the input is structured then there is a higher chance of collisions occurring.

http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/

http://www.links.org/?p=6

Comment: There are other hashing algorithms that I would imagine work better. You could always name one parameter in each function something crazy to spread out the hashing.  Haha. =)